# Django set up help in venv : Attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_version'

Tags: python, django, python-venv

After making appropriate changes with the settings.py ie. mentioning database name as sqlite3 I do:
python manage.py syncdb

It gives the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 8, in ?
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in ?
     get_version = django.get_version
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_version'
```

Please note that I have django installed in a venv directory and I have installed python in this virtualenv directory.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Normally in your venv directory there should be some binaries for python as well.

Comment: which version of django ? You are using python2.4

Comment: `get_version()` was added before django 1.0, so you should be using a very old release. Also are you sure you are using a virtualenv (you need to activate it)? In that case the path in the traceback should be `/path/to/venv/lib/site-packages/...` and not `/usr/lib...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using a virtualenv, or your venv has access to system packages, which somehow defeats one of the advantages of using them.

To create a virtualenv use

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p python2.4 ~/my_venv
```

This will create a virtualenv in your home folder giving no access to system packages. The -p switch let you select your python version: if you have a more recent python version installed you should use it, or you will only be able to use Django 1.3. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Next you need to activate it

```
$ source ~/my_venv/bin/activate
(my_venv) $
```

That new prompt shows you that you are now using your virtualenv. You can then install Django (replace that version which one you need or can use) and everything you need

```
$ pip install Django==1.3
```

Everytime you want to use your virtualenv, you will need to activate it. To ise again you default python installation use `deactivate`.

Comment: sidenote: `--no-site-packages` and `--distribute` are deprecated now because these settings became virtualenv default behavior